# Attach DatePicker to another UI Element

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="{Binding WidgetSubTitle}" Style="{StaticResource WidgetSubTitleStyle}" />

    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}">
        <DatePicker.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.Resources>
    </DatePicker>
</StackPanel>
```

which looks like

[image]

I'd like to get rid of the Calendar icon and instead 'attach' the date picker to my `Label`. When the label is clicked, I want to open the picker (which has a Two-Way binding to a `DateTime` property in my view model). I can replace the `Label` with a button too, so I can benefit from its commands, that's not a problem.

I can't figure out how to do it. I have seen a solution which puts a `Calendar` in a `Popup`, but this seems to complicate things, to me.

One solution I could imagine is - hide the entire `DatePicker` control (Visibility = Collapsed) and when the button/label is clicked, switch ON the visibility only of the calendar popup part of that picker. Can't quite figure out the styles though ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could completely change the look of a WPF control by changing its ControlTemplate. In this case you could define a custom template for the DatePicker control that basically makes it look like a Button and then define another template for the Button that makes it look like a Label. Something like this:

```
<DatePicker>
    <DatePicker.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <Button x:Name="PART_Button">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Label Content="{Binding WidgetSubTitle}" Style="{StaticResource WidgetSubTitleStyle}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DatePicker.Template>
</DatePicker>
```

The nice thing about this is that the functionality of the control remains the same even if you change its appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a custom Style for yor DatePicker control. It might look a bit like complicating things for you as well as the solution you have mentioned but it isn't. Its one of the things which make WPF as great as it is.

In WPF ControlTemplates you usually have parts, so the Implementation of the Controll knows what to do with which UI Element.

For the DatePicker you have `PART_Button` and `PART_TextBox` which you will need to customize to your needs. I.e. remove the actual button and add a Label for it.

You can read all you need for it including a great example at the msdn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215(v=vs.110).aspx